# Index out of range. Must be non-negative in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net-2010

I'm newbie to here, i'm having an error regarding the (DataGridView delete part) unable to solve with self, so come here ask for guide and help me pls....appreciation your assist!

## LOAD DATA EVENT

```
     `Public Sub loadtoDGV()
        Dim sqlq As String = "SELECT * FROM chattbl"
        Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim sqladpt As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim tbl As New DataTable

        With sqlcmd
            .CommandText = sqlq
            .Connection = conn
        End With

        With sqladpt
            .SelectCommand = sqlcmd
            .Fill(tbl)
        End With

        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        For i = 0 To tbl.Rows.Count - 1
            With DataGridView1
                .Rows.Add(tbl.Rows(i)("ChatConttentID"), tbl.Rows(i)("Title"),   tbl.Rows(i)("ChatContent"), tbl.Rows(i)("ChatDateTime"), tbl.Rows(i)("Username"))
            End With
        Next
        conn.Close()
    End Sub`
```

## DELETE PART ERROR OCCURED

```
    `If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.Open()
    End If
    For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim deletemore As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value <------{line occurred error}
        Dim sqlq As String = ("DELETE FROM chattbl WHERE ChatConttentID = " &         deletemore & "")
        Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand

        With sqlcmd
            .CommandText = sqlq
            .Connection = conn
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
    Next

    loadtoDGV()`
```

Comment: What kind of error? any error log? Throwing codes without any related logs won't help on the situation

Comment: what the size of SelectedRows Array? you are looping trough Rows collection but getting value from SelectedRows...

Comment: Moreover, the error on your topic has clearly mentioned `Index out of range. Must be non-negative` means that you are passing something which is in a negative value, most probably when `DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0`

Answer (score 0):

So I am assuming that your application is a Windows Form application and you're using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) control...sorry if this assumption is incorrect.

Your error might be because of the logic you've used to write your For loop:

```
For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim deletemore As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value <------{line occurred error}
```

You are looping through all the rows in the DataGridView and then trying to get that index out of the [SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) collection.

Your loop is making an assumption that, I think, is going to be incorrect a lot of the time in that it assumes that all rows in the DataGridView are selected (as this is the only time when the # of items in the DataGridView and the # of items in DataGridView.SelectedRows will be equal and make the loop work).

You'd probably be better served just looping through the selected rows, using something like:

```
Dim numSelectedRows = DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count

For i = 0 to (numSelectedRows - 1)
     Dim deletemore As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(i).Cells(0).Value
```

PS. There are some caveats on the [SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx) property around the selection mode for the control (see the "Remarks" section in the link). I assume that you're following those caveats.

Comment: thank very much to all of you will try to correct it, Ops... i thought my shortcut looping workable head knocking zzzzzzzzzzzz...........and i change it now my winapp no more error thanks all